# Why am I getting this deprecated warning?! MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm working with MongoDB in NodeJS,

```
    const { MongoClient, ObjectId } = require("mongodb");

const MONGO_URI = `mongodb://xxx:xxx@xxx/?authSource=xxx`; // prettier-ignore

class MongoLib {

  constructor() {
    this.client = new MongoClient(MONGO_URI, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
    });
    this.dbName = DB_NAME;
  }

  connect() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.client.connect(error => {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
        }
        resolve(this.client.db(this.dbName));
      });
    });
  }
  async getUser(collection, username) {
    return this.connect().then(db => {
      return db
        .collection(collection)
        .find({ username })
        .toArray();
    });
  }
}

let c = new MongoLib();

c.getUser("users", "pepito").then(result => console.log(result));
c.getUser("users", "pepito").then(result => console.log(result));
```

and when the last c.getUser statement is executed (that's to say, when I make a SECOND connectio) Mongodb outputs this warning:

```
the options [servers] is not supported
the options [caseTranslate] is not supported
the options [username] is not supported
the server/replset/mongos/db options are deprecated, all their options are supported at the top level of the options object [poolSize,ssl,sslValidate,sslCA,sslCert,sslKey,sslPass,sslCRL,autoReconnect,noDelay,keepAlive,keepAliveInitialDelay,connectTimeoutMS,family,socketTimeoutMS,reconnectTries,reconnectInterval,ha,haInterval,replicaSet,secondaryAcceptableLatencyMS,acceptableLatencyMS,connectWithNoPrimary,authSource,w,wtimeout,j,forceServerObjectId,serializeFunctions,ignoreUndefined,raw,bufferMaxEntries,readPreference,pkFactory,promiseLibrary,readConcern,maxStalenessSeconds,loggerLevel,logger,promoteValues,promoteBuffers,promoteLongs,domainsEnabled,checkServerIdentity,validateOptions,appname,auth,user,password,authMechanism,compression,fsync,readPreferenceTags,numberOfRetries,auto_reconnect,minSize,monitorCommands,retryWrites,useNewUrlParser]
```

But I'm not using any deprecated options. Any ideas?

---

**EDIT**

After a little discussion with *molank* in the comments, it looks like open several connections from the same server is not a good practice, so maybe that's what the warning is trying to say (badly I think). So if you have the same problem, save the connection instead of the mongo client.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Reposting from https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-1868:

The deprecation messages are likely because `client.connect` is being called multiple times. Overall, calling `client.connect` multiple times currently (as of driver `v3.1.13`) has undefined behavior, and it is not recommended. It is important to note that once the promise returned from `connect` resolves, the client remains connected until you call `client.close`:

```
const client = new MongoClient(...);

client.connect().then(() => {
  // client is now connected.
  return client.db('foo').collection('bar').insertOne({
}).then(() => {
  // client is still connected.

  return client.close();
}).then(() => {
  // client is no longer connected. attempting to use it will result in undefined behavior.
});
```

The client by default maintains multiple connections to each server it is connected to, and can be used for multiple simultaneous operations*. You should be fine running `client.connect` once, and then running your operations on the client object

* Note that the client is NOT thread-safe or fork-safe, so it cannot be shared across forks, and it not compatible with node's `cluster` or `worker_threads` modules.

Answer (score 1):

The function **`.connect()`** takes **3 arguments** and is defined as such `MongoClient.connect(url[, options], callback)`. So you need to provide an URL first, then the options and only then you give it the callback. Here is an example from the docs

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/integration_tests", { native_parser: true }, function (err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err);

    db.collection('mongoclient_test').update({ a: 1 }, { b: 1 }, { upsert: true }, function (err, result) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        assert.equal(1, result);

        db.close();
    });
});
```

Another way to go, since you already created your `MongoClient` is to use **`.open`** instead. It **only takes a callback**, but you call it from the `mongoClient` you created `(this.client)`. You ca use it like this

```
this.client.open(function(err, mongoclient) {
    // Do stuff
});
```

## Note

Make sure you check out the [MongoClient docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html#), you'll find a lot of good examples that may guide you even better.

Comment: This does not answer my question. open() is deprecated too. I'm connecting as the docs says, but when I make the SECOND connection that appears.

Comment: Who says `open` is deprecated? Because that's not mentioned in the docs. Also you didn't say you connected twice in your question

Comment: Ups my fault, open() is deprecated in mongoose but I'm not using it sorry for the confusion. And yep I forgot to say that happened in my second connection, I'm going to fix it. Sorry for the comment

Comment: I did not tell it explicitly now I do

Comment: The answer still holds, `connect` still takes 3 arguments, not just a callback

Comment: Eeemmm yeah but you can create a new instance of MongoClient(uri, options) (let's call it db) and then call db.connect(callback). Docs: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/MongoClient.html. 

Actually, if I try to use open(), it outputs an error telling that open() is not a funciton

Comment: Yeah you're right! Maybe try opening only one connection? Then save it as an attribute instead of saving the client

Comment: but I need several connections :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188260/discussion-between-molamk-and-antonio-gamiz-delgado).

Answer (score 0):

`poolSize` is deprecated, use `maxPoolSize`.